# How to count the number of closed manifolds in an alpha-shapes triangulion?

Tags: geometry, manifolds

I have used CGAL to [construct the alpha-shapes around a set of particles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2Bvi.png) representing a droplet. Therefore, I have a list of surface nodes and elements forming the triangular surface. When I visualize this information, in some cases the alpha-shapes may include more than one closed manifold (e.g. when the droplet is splashed). I was wondering to know how I can count the number of closed manifolds (not manually). Also, is there any way to get more information about the nodes and elements that construct each specific closed manifold?

Thanks

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but according to [Descartes Angular Defect Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_defect#Descartes.27_theorem) says that the total angular defect of a polyhedron homeomorphic to a sphere is $4\pi$. So I think the total angular defect of the entire assembly should come out to $4\pi\chi$, where $\chi$ is the number of droplets, which might provide a way of calculating the number of closed manifolds. But if just counting the number of droplets is all you need, then there are probably simpler ways of doing it.

Comment: For example, pick a vertex at random, and mark it as counted. Then take the set of vertices adjacent to it, and mark them as counted. Keep doing this until the process terminates. If all the vertices are counted, you have 1 droplet. Otherwise, delete the previously marked vertices, pick another uncounted vertex at random, and do it again. If all the vertices are counted, you have 2 total droplets, otherwise delete the second round of vertices and start again, etc. There may be an even faster way, but I'm not a computer scientist, so you could probably get better advice.

Comment: Thanks for your interesting advices. I actually need to know the number of droplets, as well as the coordinates of one point inside each droplet. To find a point inside each droplet, I need to figure out what are the nodes and elements that construct each droplet and maybe use some kind of ray-casting algorithm to find a point inside.